# Compare list of value with dataframe columns and if value in list found compare the data in next column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need your help on python pandas function. I am new to pandas and trying to explore it. I have a scenario where I have a list of product as below:

```
product_list=['IBM','Redhat','microsoft']
```

As well as version dictionary that I want to compare with version column based on some condition:

```
version_dict={'IBM': '8.0.0','microsoft':'9.5','Redhat':'3.1.1'}
```

I have a dataframe as below:

```css
hostname  product   version Owner   Environment
server1   IBM       3.1.1   Tom     UAT
server2   Redhat    2.1.2   Dick    PROD
server3   microsoft 10      Harry   PROD
server4   microsoft 9       Harry   UAT
server5   IBM       8.5.5   Tom     PROD
```

I want to loop in such a way that if for owner "Tom", any of the product defined in product_list found in column "product", then compare the version of the product from version_dict with column value in "version". If version is less than with the value defined in dictionary "version_dict", want to copy the entire row into separate excel file.

Comment: `for k,v in df.groupby("product"):
    if k in product_list:
        v.to_excel(......)` ?

Answer (score 1):

While not strictly a loop this might answer your question:

```
df = ... your original DF ...
product_list=['IBM','Redhat','microsoft']
version_dict={'IBM': '8.0.0','microsoft':'9.5','Redhat':'3.1.1'}
```

Select the owner and target products:

```
dfc = df[(df['Owner']=='Tom') & (df['product'].isin(product_list))].copy()
```

Lookup and set the minimum versions:

```
dfc['min_ver'] = dfc['product'].map(version_dict)
```

Find the versions that do not meet the minimum:

```
dfx = dfc[dfc.apply(lambda x: x['version']<x['min_ver'], axis=1)]

dfx

  hostname product version Owner Environment min_ver
0  server1     IBM   3.1.1   Tom         UAT   8.0.0
```

Then save as XLS:

```
dfx.to_excel(...)
```

Note the the lambda function above in the `apply()` - `lambda x: x['version']<x['min_ver']` - is **inadequate** for comparing string v.r.m's.  I include it only for illustration.  You need to replace with a real function that can properly do this comparison.  Here is an example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compare-two-version-numbers/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am able to get the correct data as well inseatd of lambda function I have used the below code which helps as expected and suggested in geeksforgeeks link.
dfc['compared_column']=np.where(dfc['version'] < dfc['min_ver'],dfc['min_ver'], np.nan)